# AWS VPC: Sample Scenario 1 - no internet access from EC2 instance without EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

i following the steps mentioned in the "Scenario 1" tutorial of AWS VPC.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html

Withing the public subnet if have an OpenSVN server which allows VPN connections to the VPC.
The server has a EIP assigned. There are no problems accessing the VPC via VPN.

If i add other EC2 instances to the VPC without a EIP the don't have access to the internet!
I have a internet gateway configured, and my route table only contains the net-local rule and the  0.0.0.0 -> internet-gateway one.

Any ideas what's missing?

If i attach an EIP to the instance, it works.

Thanks
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During all the VPC tutorial testing i deleted my "default vpc".

Without the default VPC, the EC2 instances will not get a public IP.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/509136/how-do-i-set-a-vpc-in-aws-to-default-vpc-true

I have to contact the amazon support.

Update: There is a (new?) option in the awscli which solve the problem --associate-public-ip-address

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html